# Screwdriver for 13-inch MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

Does anyone know what is the precision screwdriver to use in opening a 13-inch Macbook Pro (Late 2011)? Need to make sure before I head to the hardware shop. Thanks.

Comment: Look what's suggested there: http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+Display+Replacement/7653

Comment: @Larme Thank you. Got my answer via the link you mentioned. Please post it as an answer and I would gladly award you the "accept" points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, according to [iFixit Tutorial for a MBP 13" Late 2011](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+Display+Replacement/7653), for the case, you'll need:

- Three 14.4 mm Phillips #00 screws
- Three 3.5 mm Phillips #00 screws
- Four 3.5 mm shouldered Phillips #00 screws

If you need more information about others screws, please refers to others tutorials on this website about what you wanna change.